# Why must my C++ function have different pointer arguments?

Tags: c++, pointers, function-declaration

I made a C function with pointer-passing which gives the right result only if the pointers are different. For instance:

```
void dotransform(Point *pout, const Point *pin, transform mat)
{
    pout->x = mat[0][0] * pin->x + mat[1][0] * pin->y + mat[2][0] * pin->z + mat[3][0] * 1.0;
    pout->y = mat[0][1] * pin->x + mat[1][1] * pin->y + mat[2][1] * pin->z + mat[3][1] * 1.0;
    pout->z = mat[0][2] * pin->x + mat[1][2] * pin->y + mat[2][2] * pin->z + mat[3][2] * 1.0;
}
```

`dotransform()` is supposed to be called like this:

```
//...
Transform toWorldMat;
Point local;
Point world;
dotransform(&world, &local, toWorldMat );
```

The problem is, someone in my team called it like this:

```
Point p;
dotransform(&p, &p, toWorldMat);
```

It just took me one week to figure out why the final output of the program changed.

What is the best style to declare this kind of function, to avoid this case? Am I wrong to write it like that?

Comment: Only send one `Point` parameter, `pin`, and use your otherwise-useless function return value as the output result.

Comment: You're (presumably) using C++: Don't pass objects by pointer for trivial examples like this. Pass by reference.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as you're already passing the `transform` object directly (though not by `const&`: you should really do that instead) is there any reason you can't write the code like so:

```
Point dotransform(Point const& pin, transform const& mat)
{
    Point pout
    pout.x = mat[0][0] * pin.x + mat[1][0] * pin.y + mat[2][0] * pin.z + mat[3][0] * 1.0;
    pout.y = mat[0][1] * pin.x + mat[1][1] * pin.y + mat[2][1] * pin.z + mat[3][1] * 1.0;
    pout.z = mat[0][2] * pin.x + mat[1][2] * pin.y + mat[2][2] * pin.z + mat[3][2] * 1.0;
    return pout;
}
```

Which would then allow you to write code like this:

```
Transform toWorldMat;
Point local;
Point world = dotransform(local, toWorldMat);
```

Or this:

```
Point p;
p = dotransform(p, toWorldMat);
```

These are the correct, ideomatic C++ ways to write this code.